# Git repository with multiple users on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, security, git, ubuntu, repository

I have an existing bare git repository located in /home/myaccount/git/project. I am currently using it over ssh from my local machine without any problems. I want to add a second user on the server which only shall access to this git repository (maybe move the repo outside my account folder?). How? Using latest version of git and ubuntu on slicehost.

I have this setup:
user: sleepyhead
user: developer1
group: git. both sleepyhead and developer1 are members of this group
repository /home/sleepyhead/git/project1

I want to:
move repository to a proper place, either /home/git/project1 or /usr/local/git/project1. What is recommended?
developer1 should permissions to read and write project1 with git. no other permissions should be given.

I do not know how to properly set the permissions and to restrict developer1 to only have access using git to project1.

Answer (score 11):

Have him create a ssh keypair and send you the public key.

Add the public key to your `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file, and add the `command="..."` option to limit it to the git-shell - see [this link](http://kitenet.net/~joey/blog/entry/locking_down_ssh_authorized_keys/) for an example.

Answer (score 4):

Orip's answer is probably all you need. If you want something a little more automated you might want to look at [gitosis](http://scie.nti.st/2007/11/14/hosting-git-repositories-the-easy-and-secure-way)

Answer (score 1):

You will also probably want to have both of those users in the same user group, and to make sure you have group-write privileges on the repository.

Comment: i have updated my question. basically what you are saying is exactly what i want to know how to accomplish